# Turn on laptop with a mouse or keyboard

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, shutdown

I have a laptop MSI GT70 2PC Dominator. How to setup this to be able to turn on with a external mouse or keyboard (USB connected)?

These are my BIOS settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thx, fixed

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes, external keyboard and mouse

Comment: Send your computer to sleep instead of shutdown.

Comment: @harrymc I prefer shutdown or hibernate if I go for a long period of time :) that's why i need this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to wake the computer with either mouse or keyboard when in hibernation state, and certainly not in the shut-down state.

Hibernation is the same as turning the computer off, except that the state the computer was in when going into hibernation mode is written to the hibernation partition/file, which will allow for faster boot and returning to your exact state as when hibernating.

Sleep is the only state where the mouse or keyboard can wake up the computer.

There is however one method for waking up a computer that is hibernating,
which is by using
[Wake-on-LAN](https://www.howtogeek.com/70374/how-to-geek-explains-what-is-wake-on-lan-and-how-do-i-enable-it/).

You need to send the magic packet that will trigger the Wake-on-LAN via an external
device, which can be your computer, the router, or any other device on your home
network. With the right configuration, this can even be done from the Internet.
This requires hardware support by the motherboard and network adapter of the
target computer.

Wake-on-LAN is a large subject which cannot be summarized here.
If you decide to try it, study my above link, and you may return to our site
for further questions.